# Curl to Javascript fetch, Access-Control-Allow-Headers problem

Tags: javascript, fetch

I have a little situation here.

Heres a curl request that 100% works (documentation):

```
curl -X GET "myUrl" -H "accept: application/json" -H "token: myToken"
```

I'm trying to rewrite it to javascript fetch or $.ajax. None of them works.

Code:

```
fetch(requestUrl, {
    method: 'GET',
    credentials: 'same-origin', // include, *same-origin, omit
    headers: new Headers({
        'accept': 'application/json',
        'token': 'myToken'
    }),
})
```

Error im getting:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'myUrl' from origin 'myOrigin' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field token is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

If I'm getting it right, is there any way, how to pass that token in headers, even if "header field token is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers"? Or is it possible to controll that preflight somehow?

Thank you guys.

Comment: What are the actual (URL) domains of the API and the page where the JS runs?

Comment: "*Or is it possible to control that preflight response somehow?*" - yes, the server needs to do that. Is this your own API?

Comment: @Bergi Im playing at my localhost, the API is https://rest.giriton.com/apidoc/, I cant controll the headers there..

Comment: In that case, you should either write your own API server (running on your domain) that proxies the requests, or contact the developer of that API to ask them for adding CORS. However, if you are building a website only to access data from your own account, you probably should not share your access token with any visitor of the website anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your back-end needs to support an OPTIONS variant of the `requestUrl` (whatever the path is) that returns a response with a header `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: token`.

You should see that before your `GET` fetch request is made, there's an `OPTIONS`, the browser is looking for the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` in the `OPTIONS` response.

Comment: Yeah, but its not my Endpoint, its some API.
How the Curl do it? Maybe because its on different network layer?

Comment: Curl can make the request because there isn't any security protocol that is preventing the request from going through. Fetch uses the browser's network request engine, which protects users from unauthorized cross origin request. Your request in nature is cross origin, from localhost to rest.grition.com.

Comment: interesting, i have the same issue, so how do we circumvent this then?